# How to develop Serial Port with Qt Embedded

Tags: qt, embedded

I'm developping an software with Qt Embedded 4.7.1. Now, I need communicate with other device via Serial Port (sush as RS232), if anyone has some advice how to do that? Is there such a class in QtCore?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such class in QtCore, but there is [QextSerialPort](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) project. I'm not sure it will work with your OS,but you may at least look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.1(next release) includes QtSerialPort as a new module. It supports Windows, Mac and Linux!

QtSerialPort info:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort